# Find the order of importance of random variables in their ability to explain a variance of Y

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, linear-regression

Problem statement:
Given a set of random variables Xs, give the order of importance of their ability to explain variance in target variable Y. Assumes all Xs are normalised to have 0 mean and std dev of 1.

Can treat this as regression problem(normal or ordinal)

Solution for 2 cases:
Case 1: When the calculated covariance matrix is diagonal, I know that random variables Xs are independent wrt each other. Then I can fit a linear regression model and order Xs by their weights.

Case 2: Or If I know that Xs are independent(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)
even though their covariance in non zero, I can fit linear regression model and order Xs by weights.

How do I solve this problem when I know that random variable Xs are not independent and have non zero covariance?

Also how can I use a non linear model such as random forest to get variable importance? scikit provides feature_importances_ api for random forest.... Is there an gotcha with this api such as results are not meaningful when variables are dependent or covariant?

Found this question elsewhere: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202221/for-linear-classifiers-do-larger-coefficients-imply-more-important-features/202846

Comment: Principal component analysis should do the job: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Answer (score 2):

**Decision trees** are by nature immune to multi-collinearity. So by that principal so is **Random Forest**. For example, if you have 2 features which are 99% correlated, when deciding upon a split the tree will choose only one of them. Other models such as Logistic regression would use both the features. - follow [this link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12597/30578) to know more.

For other models, solutions can be many, but here are the popular choices -

**Regularization**

This is an automatic way of handling high correlations in your Xs. It decreases the value of the co-efficients by penalizing them against the loss function and introduces bias in the system. Popular implementations are `L1`, `L2` and `Elastic Net`(in case of linear and logistic models), `Pruning`(in case of Decision Trees), `Dropout` and `max pooling` in case of deep learning.

Almost all `sklearn` implementations support a regularization parameter in 1 way or the other. Depends on the algorithm you are using.

**Using VIF to detect multi-collinearity**

[Variance Inflation Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) is a metric that you can use with all your Xs and then start dropping variables with the highest VIF *one by one* (usually the variable with the highest VIF is dropped and then the exercise is repeated till there is no multi-collinearity left or domain experts come in and choose what important variables to keep/drop)

**Principal Component Analysis**

Although the model might lose its interpretability (you won't be able to tell exactly what feature is how important), `PCA` has been another effective way of removing multi-collinearity. Basically it projects the data in a way that the output columns are orthogonal (independent)

**Some Examples**

[Ridge Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html)

```
 from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
 import numpy as np
 n_samples, n_features = 10, 5
 np.random.seed(0)
 y = np.random.randn(n_samples)
 X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)
 clf = Ridge(alpha=1.0)
 clf.fit(X, y)
```

[Lasso Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html)

```
 from sklearn import linear_model
 clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)
 clf.fit([[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
```

[Elastic Net](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNet.html)

```
 from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
 from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

 X, y = make_regression(n_features=2, random_state=0)
 regr = ElasticNet(random_state=0)
 regr.fit(X, y)
```

[Random Forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)
 - Almost all parameters in scikit-learn can account for regularization here

[Statsmodels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence.variance_inflation_factor.html) has a rather good implementation of VIF

[PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2) # adjust yourself
pca.fit(X)

X_t_train = pca.transform(X)
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_t_train, y)
```